# errors when deploying a Flex PHP Zend project from localhost on a linux web server

Tags: php, zend-framework, flex4.5

I have developed my project on my local system and works fine on wamp. Now I tried to transfer it into a webserver, but unfortunatedly I am getting the following error whenever I perform a service call.

```
Class "LoginService" does not exist: Plugin by name 'LoginService' was not found in the registry; used paths:
#0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Amf/Server.php(553): Zend_Amf_Server->_dispatch('loginHandler', Array, 'LoginService...')
#1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Amf/Server.php(629): Zend_Amf_Server->_handle(Object(Zend_Amf_Request_Http))
#2 /var/www/html/Fotokiklosi-PHP/public/gateway.php(68): Zend_Amf_Server->handle()
#3 {main}
```

I have installed the Zend Framework and the only change I made was the endpoint value of my service from localhost to the ip of the server.

Comment: is it your database authentication problem? Check it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem eventually was caused by a missed setup on the amf_config.ini. I commented out most of the entries there and kept the stuff I considered most straightforward.So eventually I ended up with the following:

```
[zend]
webroot = /var/www/html/myProject/
[zendamf]
amf.production = false
amf.directories[]=services
```

Note: services is a folder inside /var/www/html/myProject/